# Having trouble with " onreadystatechange " , not working ! Win8 dev , and Idea why this happens?

Tags: javascript

I am have this wired problem, every time the  "onreadystatechange" called its not returning anything. for example I remove the if and I tell it to return yes that the state of the ajax change its still not returning instead I will get undefined any Idea why this is happening ?

```
    function load_page(php_handler, url ,searchString) {


        // Get the ajax object using our function above.
        window.ajax = makeAJAXObject();

        // Tell the AJAX object what to do when it's loaded the page
        window.ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (window.ajax.readyState == 4) { // 4 means it's loaded ok.
                // For simplicity, I'll just return this

                     return ("yes");
            }
        }

        // Set up the variables you want to sent to your PHP page (namely, the URL of the page to load)
        var queryString = "?url=" + url;
        // Load the PHP script that opens the page
        window.ajax.open("GET", php_handler + queryString, true);
        window.ajax.send(null);


        }
```

here is my makeAJAXObject function

```
function makeAJAXObject() { // seems to be working ok 
        var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

        try {
            // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
            ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
            // Internet Explorer Browsers
            try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {
                    // Something went wrong
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return ajaxRequest;
    }
```

I also tried to copy a working version of the script from example I found here and the same thing happens, I am working on the split form that coming with the studio.

Please help !

Comment: What is the purpose of `return` in that function called when request is completed, how do you think?

Comment: I'd recommend using jQuery for cross browser AJAX support. That being said, have you tried to find out what makeAJAXObject() is returning? I assume it is returning false.

Comment: Can you tell with firebug what the server response is ? (status and body)

Comment: Do you know how Asynchronous requests work? That return is not going to do anything.

Comment: Your code executes fine on chrome after swapping return ("yes"); with alert("yes");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning a value from your state change handler will have no effect. When the browser invokes your function, it will pay no attention to anything that's returned.

Change that to an `alert` or `console.log` or something to prove to yourself that it works.

Comment: Is that what he meant by returns nothing? I thought he was talking about the `makeAJAXObject()` function. Kudos for being able to decipher this mess.

Comment: @crush well it's not super-clear what the OP wants, but a `return` statement with a value in an event handler is always a red flag :-)

Comment: The return statement  is just to test if the ready state is really 4, if its really works when how I send the result to another function ?

Comment: You call the function in the callback! ;)

Comment: @DanielIliaguevHarta yes, everything has to be controlled from within the callback function. That's the basic nature of code structure in an asynchronous system like JavaScript in a browser or Win8 apps.

Comment: Hmm.. I am trying it now Like you said However it's just don't work, can make something like this : log = "yes"; and return it after function ?

Comment: @DanielIliaguevHarta again: using `return` from inside the event handler will just exit the handler. The browser will ignore the return value. Try `console.log("hello world");` and that should show up in the browser console, assuming your HTTP request is actually working.

Comment: @Pointy  
Sorry for my stupidy but the thing is that I have no Idea how i summon later the console log so i will see in in the app itself, this function is in .js file and I need need to show it in the html file. How I summon the console.log in the html page ? On again sorry for being stupid javascript is very new to me.

Comment: @DanielIliaguevHarta the console is part of the web browser; it's a diagnostic tool for developers. It's not something you use for your actual web site. It's just for testing. Exactly how you see it depends on your web browser, but for example in Chrome you just hit F12.